# For loop not providing correct integers? Syntax error?

Tags: c++, for-loop, syntax, infinite-loop

The prompt for this question is:

> First, read in an input value for variable inCount. Then, read inCount integers from input and output each integer on a newline after the string "number-".

The code I'm using is

```
for (int inCount = 0; inCount <= 90; inCount++) {
      cin >> inCount;
      cout << "number-" << inCount << endl;
}
```

The program tests this code with a few sets of numbers to see if the code works properly and isn't accidentally an IL or something, but to save space I'll just share the first one:

My output:

```
number-5
number-30
number-85
number-90
```

The correct output:

```
number-30
number-85
number-90
number-65
number-70
```

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong? Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

I think they were describing something more like this

```
int count = 0;
std::cin >> count;

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    int value = 0;
    std::cin >> value;
    std::cout << "number-" << value << std::endl;
}
```

In other words `count` represents how many values to read in, then loop that many times and write out the value that was provided each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example using while loop.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World"<<std::endl;
    int count = 0;
    std::cin >> count;

while(count > 0)
{
    int value = 0;
    std::cin >> value;
    std::cout << "number-" << value << std::endl;
    
    --count;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable to both drive your loop and read the user's input into.  As soon as a number `>= 90` is entered by the user, `inCount++` increments `inCount` to a value that is `> 90` causing your loop condition to break.

You need to use separate variables instead, eg:

```cpp
int inCount;
cin >> inCount;

for (int i = 0; i < inCount; ++i) {
    int inNumber;
    cin >> inNumber;
    cout << "number-" << inNumber << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
       int inCount;
       char wildChar;
       cin >> inCount;
       wildChar = '*';

       for (int i = 0; i < inCount; ++i) {
          int inVal = 0;
          cin >> inVal;
          cout << inVal;
          if (i == inCount - 1)
          cout << endl;
          else 
          cout << wildChar;
       }

       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please include an explanation for why the code is supposed to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).